# foreach 2 array ( checkbox and text input)

Tags: php, sql

What's wrong with my code. Cant pass text input values.

```
$item1=$_POST['product'];
$item2=$_POST['id'];
foreach ($item1 as $k=>$get1){
    $addsql = "insert into referral (product, ID) values ('$get1','$item2[$k]')";
    $addresult = mysql_query($addsql, $link);    
}
```

Picture:

[image]

table result:

```
Product       ID
Liabilities   null
Marine        null
Medical       1
```

HTML:

```
echo "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='product[]'  value='Mosbite'>&nbsp;Mosbite</td><td width='400'><input type='checkbox' name='product[]'  value='Fire'>&nbsp;Fire <input type='text' name='id[]' value='{$_POST['id']}' size='40' ></td></tr>"; 
echo "<tr><td></td><td width='400'><input type='checkbox' name='product[]'  value='Liabilities'>&nbsp;Liabilities <input type='text' name='id[]' value='{$_POST['id']}' size='40' ></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td></td><td width='400'><input type='checkbox' name='product[]'  value='Marine'>&nbsp;Marine <input type='text' name='id[]' value='{$_POST['id']}' size='40' ></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td></td><td width='400'><input type='checkbox' name='product[]'  value='Medical'>&nbsp;Medical <input type='text' name='id[]' value='{$_POST['id']}' size='40' ></td></tr>";
```

Comment: ` $addsql = "insert into referral () values ('$get1','$item2[$k]')";` .I think here u should add variables as like `$addsql = "insert into referral (product, ID) values ('$get1','$item2[$k]')";`

Comment: @alvin $addsql = "insert into referral (product, ID) values ('".$get1."','".$k."')";  check this

Comment: @NaveenN he does not need that if his table column count is equal to the number of passed parameters

Comment: var_dump($_POST); and check it out product id and product values

Comment: It would be great to see how the html is generated (or the source of that html), also, mysql_* is deprecated and this code is absolutely vulnerable to sql injections, you should be careful when directly parsing get and post values inside your query.

Comment: there might be an issue in the HTML, could you post that too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the most obvious problem is that there is no $_POST['id'] in the HTML you've shown, only $_POST['sub'] and $_POST['product'].